# Why is my meta info not sharing properly?

Tags: facebook, share

I have recently finished my site http://wwww.cute-or-not.com
When I share it on Facebook, no meta info or image comes through even though I have set this in WordPress using SEO Yoast. Am I missing something obvious

Answer (score 1):

`http://wwww.cute-or-not.com` is most likely not what you want, maybe you meant `http://www.cute-or-not.com`

Using the debugger, http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cute-or-not.com%2F

> More Than One OG URL Specified:   Object at URL 'http://www.cute-or-not.com/' of type 'article' is invalid because it specifies multiple 'og:url' values: http://www.cute-or-not.com/, http://www.cute-or-not.com/.

You are defining the OG meta tags twice. Remove it from the "Easy Facebook Share Thumbnails" plugin.

Comment: i experienced the same problem on http://www.mismo.rs
i have autoshare on facebook page, and everytime i have to delete that post on facebook, go to debugger, "scrape new info" few times, untill it reads meta tags properly, and only then i share it again on facebook.
all this time i change nothing on website itself